# upstream/HEAD listed in remote branches

Tags: git

I've noticed something weird in my list of remote git branches. I seem to be the only one of my coworkers who notices the following line when I run `git branch -r`:

```
upstream/HEAD -> upstream/7.3.0
```

No matter what I seem to do I can't get this to go away, and I'm now running into some issues that make me think this may be the root cause. Does anyone know what this means, the implications of it, and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

Git creates this indirect (symbolic) reference on initial `git clone` in what appears to be a misguided attempt to be useful and/or informative.  Subsequent `git fetch` operations may or may not re-create or update it (in testing recently I found that `git fetch` would not touch it, but in the past I have seen it get re-created).

You can delete it manually with `git branch -r -d upstream/HEAD`.

It *should* always be harmless, even if it is incorrect.

Comment: Do you know why I would see this when I run `git branch -r` but not my coworkers? Would this have any effect on a folder structure not being duplicated from upstream when I fetch or pull down new changes?

Comment: I believe it's Git-version-dependent (compare your and their `git --version`s).  And, no, it should not affect anything like that.